# Rails 3 Overriding Devise Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, actionmailer, mailchimp

I am working on an app that is tightly being integrated in with Mandrill (MailChimp's transactional email service) and I am trying to override the Devise Mailer but for some reason when I send off the API call to Mandrill I receive their email, but Devise also sends me an email (which is blank).

Here is my `DeviseMailer`

```
class MyDeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer
  def reset_password_instructions(record)
    mandrill = Mandrill::API.new("#{MandrillConfig.api_key}")
    mandrill.messages 'send-template',
            { 
              :template_name => 'Forgot Password', 
              :template_content => "",
              :message => {
                :subject => "Forgot Password",
                :from_email => "test@test123.com",
                :from_name => "Company Support",
                :to => [
                  {
                    :email => record.email
                  }
                ],
                :global_merge_vars => [
                  {
                    :name => "FIRST_NAME",
                    :content => record.first_name
                  },
                  {
                    :name => "FORGOT_PASSWORD_URL",
                    :content => "<a href='#{edit_user_password_url(:reset_password_token => record.reset_password_token)}'>Change My Password</a>"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
      #We need to call super because Devise doesn't think we have sent any mail 
      super
  end
end
```

The call to `super` I found here: http://qnundrum.com/answer.php?q=254917

Comment: Just I thought, but have you tried to override the `config.mailer` option in **devise.rb**?

Comment: I did, devise is still sending out the email because you have to call super at the bottom of your override

Comment: What happens if you leave out the call to super?

Comment: I'm stuck with this problem -- did you manage to solve it? I'm thinking of skipping the `super` and manually setting `confirmation_sent_at`, but I'm not sure if it'll work

Answer (score 12):

I was running into a similar issue.

Did you update the devise initializer file (devise.rb) to specify the following:

```
config.mailer = "MyDeviseMailer"
```

You also needed to move any and all files in views/devise/mailer to views/mydevisemailer.

I would also restart your server.